# Lost EC2 ssh login after removing zsh

Tags: amazon-ec2, zsh

I had `zsh` installed on one of my EC2 instance, I didn't like it much, so removed it.

`$ sudo apt-get remove zsh`

`$ exit`

And exited from my instance. Now I'm not able to log in back with error `Permission denied (publickey).`

There is no other user with whom I can log in. I checked several similar questions for Ubuntu machine, found that we can fix this by logging into single user mode, but how to do this on AWS EC2?

I think I missed the part `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash <username>`.

How do I get back ssh login? I have a Basic support plan on AWS which does not have `Technical Support`.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you do the following:

> 1. Stop your instance
> 2. Detach the volume
> 3. Create new instance
> 4. Attach the volume from your problematic instance to the new instance
> 5. Mount it on /mnt/something or where ever you want so that you could have access to it

Manually fix the shell for the user you're trying to log in. One you're done, detach the volume from instance #2 and attach it to your main instance.

Comment: By manually fixing the shell, do you mean that I just edit the `/etc/passwd` file in the mounted problematic instance volume?

Comment: Yes, that's one option. You can also chroot and use `chsh`, but try with `/etc/passwd` first.